# Buck- Boost converter failed on surge at 500volts

Tags: mosfet, surge-protection, buck-boost, solar-charge-controller

##### Basic Technical Details

The driver is basically a DC solar charge controller, it's used in solar street lights, it requires a battery and panel. This driver uses the Buck-Boost Topology. At night it behaves as a Boost converter from battery to the lamp load. In sunlight - when charging -  it behaves as a Buck converter.

- Load - 12W
- Battery - Li-Po4 (12.8v)
- Panel - 75W (21VDC)

##### Problem

To cope with thunderstorms and other upsets, we need to test the driver circuit to withstand overvoltages on the connections to battery and load.

The test procedure uses a 1000V pulse, of either polarity, at the panel input side.

Our initial choice of circuit protection is a MOV as shown in the circuit diagram below. The MOV part# is CVR 40D14. With this MOV, the circuit failed at a positive surge of 750 volts and also failed at a negative surge of 500 volts. The mosfets are rated 40V maximum.

##### Question

How to choose the right protection circuitry to pass 1000 volts surge ?

If you want any other technical details please let me know.

[image: a fragment of the schematic of the driver circuit, showing the buck-boost mosfets, and the location of the MOV]

Comment: What surge testing method was being used and what specification of surge test was implemented (hint: it might be EN 61000-4-5 but you need to state this). You'll also need to state what source impedance was used for the surge and surges were applied to your circuit. You also need to state what the maximum working voltage on the Vout line will be under normal working conditions.

Comment: Presumably the two "Gate drive" inputs are different signals, and presumably it is Q2 and/or its "Gate Drive" (not shown) which fails. We need to see that gate drive circuit, and please explain how it limits Vgs to the range permitted by Q2's datasheet (not linked). You might also clarify why both FETs are the same part number, yet one is N type and the other P type.

Comment: You need to increase the impedance at high frequencies to make your MOV setup (more) effective. Can you place a choke there?

Answer (score 0):

If the MOV "almost" does the job, then a gas discharge tube in parallel will solve the problem. You could try with a simple neon bulb connected across (between + and -) on all three external connections: the battery connection, the panel connection, and the lamp/LED connection. Any neon bulb type will do.

If that works, then you should select a suitable gas discharge tube, and repeat the test. The GDT should have high enough voltage rating (say 300V) so the arc sustaining voltage and current won't cause latch-up when the battery is fully charged *and* the panel is in full sunlight.

Gas discharge tubes (GDTs) go into arc operating region when presented with high current + high voltage inputs like lightning or electrostatic discharges. Their impedance in the arc regime is low, and the voltage across them will be quite low as well - perhaps in the 10-20V range. The arc will be sustained as long as enough current is available on the input - usually 0.5A or more. In your application, a fully charged battery just might have enough voltage to latch the GDT in the arc mode. This will destroy the GDT - it can't be dissipating tens of Watts for long without melting. It will also shorten the life of the battery due to high current discharge. The solar panel also has plenty of current capacity and even higher voltage to keep a GDT latched in an arc for as long as sunlight is present :)

The arc can be quenched timely by using a PTC poly fuse on external (+) connections, i.e. before the panel or battery circuit reaches the MOV.

---

Side note: Most neon bulbs are quite tolerant of high currents (1-20mA) as long as you don't overheat them, and they work reasonably well as switches in electronic "retro" circuits like relay computers and such. A typical neon bulb acts like a 60-80V Zener diode once it's glowing, and this voltage stays relatively constant between a fraction of mA and hundreds of mA. At sufficiently high current - usually hundreds of mA - it goes from glow discharge to arc discharge, and its Zener voltage drops to 10-20V. There are significant problems in effectively cooling both the envelope and the electrodes of neon bulbs that dissipate 5-10W while arcing. It's less of a problem with gas discharge tubes, since they have much larger electrodes that you can attach directly to a heatsink, and their arc voltages are at least half that of a neon bulb. The typical GDT has a ceramic envelope that may be slightly translucent, so you can see some white light escaping from the arc discharge inside.

Answer (score 0):

When i took my product for CE certification i go through same problem then  study different type of protection circuits. But what i fidn best is TVS Didoes . But you need to me very clear about its selection. When you perform any Surge and EFT test note down how much current your device pass through that TVS diode .For me **5.0SMDJ12CA** work perfectly I think you can also test with **8.0SMDJ12CA**

Please you can try with TVS diode available with **[littelfuse](https://www.littelfuse.com/)**.

[5.0SMDJ12CA / 8.0SMDJ12CA](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_5_0smdj_datasheet.pdf.pdf) .
You can use at input connector of your design very close to your power connector.  and also if possible please share you layout. when you place this TVS Diode. Please go through Datasheet attached.

Sorry for any mistake I do while answer